# How to limit the number of 'Recent Blogs' created in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create a blog, and in every single blog it shows the recent blogs that has been created on the bottom of the page. Is there a way i can limit this number to 4 recent blogs? Because currently all the blogs that has been created show's up on the "Recent Blogs" area when i generate it.

```
 <div class="container" id="newsextra">
    <h4>MORE NEWS</h4>
    <div class="row">

        <?php 
        if(!empty($error)){
        echo $error;
    }
    if (!empty($blogsinfos)) {  
    foreach ($blogsinfos as $blogs): ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="/news-single/<?=  h($blogs->id)?>">
        <img src="<?=  h($blogs->mainimg)?>" class="img-responsive">
        <h5><?=  h($blogs->title)?></h5>
        <h6><?=  h($blogs->created)?></h6>
        </a>
    </div>

      <?php 
    endforeach; 
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, go to the controller and find the function from where `$blogsinfos` is being set to the view. Then, modify the query for `$blogsinfos` by setting the limit to 4.

Comment: you need to define a limit in your request like this example.

$this->find()->limit(4)->order(['date' => 'desc])

Comment: @Gransfall

Do you mean like this ? 

    $this->loadModel('Blogs');
    $opts1['conditions'] =  array('Blogs.status' => 1);
    $blogsinfos = $this->Blogs->find('all',$opts1);
    $this->set('blogsinfos', $blogsinfos);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['blogsinfos']);
    $this->find()->limit(4)->order(['date' => 'desc]')


    foreach ($blogsinfos as $blogs) {
        $proid = $blogs['id'];
    }

Comment: Try `$opts1['limit'] = 4;` Place this before using the `find()`.

Comment: @Rik.esh $opts1['limit'] = 4; works to limit the number of post to 4, but how do i get the latest post?

Comment: Then also add this line : `$opts1['order'] = array('Blogs.created' => 'desc');`

Comment: Got it working. Thanks @Rik.esh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the controller you should limit the number of posts generated. Thanks @Rik.esh for the answer.

```
 $this->loadModel('Blogs');
 $opts1['conditions'] =  array('Blogs.status' => 1);
 $opts1['limit'] = 4;
 $opts1['order'] = array('Blogs.created' => 'desc');
 $blogsinfos = $this->Blogs->find('all',$opts1);
 $this->set('blogsinfos', $blogsinfos);
 $this->set('_serialize', ['blogsinfos']);

 foreach ($blogsinfos as $blogs) {
    $proid = $blogs['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$opts1['order'] = 'Blogs.created desc';
```